# JMeter HTTP Request shows a second failed result of a wrong URL

Tags: jmeter

My results tree shows a separate status for a URL connection I have absolutely no idea where it might come from:
[image: wrong url]

The first result with the `-0` at the end is that of the request I send willingly. The other connection with the `-1` comes out of the void.

In the response body I can see that JMeter fails while trying to resolve the DNS name:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: aida.xyz.removed
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
```

This is my definition of the HTTP Request:
[image: URL I want to access]

As you can see this goes to a totally different host and protocol (http instead of https).
I checked the defined csv, it does not contain the hostname "aid". Same goes for the JMX file and any environment variables set.

I am using Apache JMeter 5.0

After I read Ubiks answer I checked if there are any redirects in the first request. There are no redirects but in the content there are several `script` and `img` resources.
It looks like JMeter parses the first request for resources it has to download. But I didn't enable this setting / don't even know where to activate this.

[image: Jmeter scans for dependencies and downloads them]

Comment: What is the decription of the request?

Comment: @user7294900 By description do you mean the name ? It is `getContent für Datei ID` (I updated the screenshot). I already removed the Umlaut to see if this changes something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it’s either a redirect issued from response to the first request or because JMeter tries to download embedded resources.

Check the response of first request.

If the reason is that JMeter downloads (probably missing) resources, make sure you disable `Retrieve All Embedded Resources` in the `Advanced` tab.

[image: Advanced / Retrieve all Embedded Resources]

Comment: If so, would I see this when I check the response headers of the successful attempt ?

Comment: yes, show in view results tree all the tabs and subtabs ?

Comment: I think I found something, it is not because of redirects. Please have a look at the updated question

Comment: Ouch, that was it. I didn't even see the Advanced tab :-|

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting indicates the problem with the system under test, JMeter cannot resolve an **embedded resource** - image, script, style, font, iframe, whatever.

You need to raise an issue as not available content is not good i.e. for [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) purposes, moreover it might be essential for your application functionality of [LAF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look_and_feel)

If this is a known issue which is in process of fixing (or considered as won't fix) you can turn JMeter's check for embedded resources presence by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

More information:

- [JMeter Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)